# How would I add a running timer that shows up on the screen in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This is just a simple fruit catching game.

```
import pygame, random, time, os, webbrowser
from time import sleep
from pygame import* 
pygame.init()
myname=input('What is your name')

#set the window size
window= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600) ,0,24)
pygame.display.set_caption("Fruit Catch")

#game variables
gameover=pygame.image.load('gameover.jpg')
myscore=0
file = 'score.txt'
eating=pygame.mixer.Sound('data/eating.wav')
die=pygame.mixer.Sound('die.wav')
mylives=3
mouth_x=300
fruit_x=250
fruit_y=75
fruitlist=['broccoli.gif','chicken.gif']
keyclicks=0
#prepare for screen
myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 55)
label1=myfont.render(myname, 1, (240, 0, 0))
label3=myfont.render(str(mylives), 1, (20, 255, 0))
#grapchics
fruit=pygame.image.load('data/chicken.png')
mouth=pygame.image.load('data/v.gif')
backGr=pygame.image.load('data/kfc.jpg')
backGr1=pygame.image.load('sj.jpg')
#endless loop

start=pygame.image.load('chibro.jpg')
end_it=False
while (end_it==False):
    window.blit(start, (0,0))
    myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 55)
    label7=myfont.render("Welcome "+myname+" Click here to begin", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 30)
    label8=myfont.render("Catch as much Chicken and brocoli as you can", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    label9=myfont.render("If you miss 3, you will starve to death!", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            end_it=True
    window.blit(label7,(10,500))
    window.blit(label8,(10,300))
    window.blit(label9,(10,400))
    pygame.display.update() 
running=True
while running:
    if fruit_y>=460:#check if at bottom, if so prepare new fruit
       fruit_x=random.randrange(50,530,1)
       fruit_y=75
       fruit=pygame.image.load('data/'+fruitlist[random.randrange(0,2,1)])
    else:fruit_y+=5

   #check collision
    if fruit_y>=456:
       mylives-=1
    if fruit_y>=440:
            if fruit_x>=mouth_x and fruit_x<=mouth_x+300 :
                    myscore+=1
                    fruit_y=600#move it off screen
                    eating.play()

    pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                        mouth_x-=55
                        keyclicks+=1
                if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                        mouth_x+=55
                        keyclicks+=1 
            if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and keyclicks>=2 :
                pygame.quit()
    label3=myfont.render(str(mylives), 1, (20, 255, 0))
    label2=myfont.render(str(myscore), 1, (20, 255, 0))
    text1='You caught'+str(myscore)
    text3='Press the mouse to close the game'
    label4=myfont.render(text1, 1, (135, 206, 250))
    myfont1=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 40)
    label5=myfont1.render(text3, 1, (255, 0, 0))

    if mylives==0:
       window.blit(gameover, (0,0))
       window.blit(label4, (500,400))
       die.play()
       pygame.time.get_ticks
       pygame.display.update()
       running=False
       webbrowser.open(file)

    else:

        window.blit(backGr,(0,0))
        window.blit(mouth, (mouth_x,440))
        window.blit(fruit,(fruit_x, fruit_y))
        window.blit(label1, (174, 537))
        window.blit(label2, (700, 157))
        window.blit(label3, (700, 400))
        window.blit(label5, (10, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

How would I make it so that when the main loop starts and running is true a timer shows up on screen counting up in seconds and the timer ends when running is false
any ideas guys?

Answer (score 3):

Use [pygame.time.get_ticks()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks)

full example - time in milliseconds, timer is centered on screen, ESC - exit, SPACE - pause timer

**EDIT:** Now it shows minutes, seconds, milliseconds - Python 2.x. For Python 3.x use `//` in place of `/` for `counting_minutes`, `counting_seconds`.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (800,600) )

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 32)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

paused  = False
running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                paused = not paused

    if not paused:
        counting_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time

        # change milliseconds into minutes, seconds, milliseconds
        counting_minutes = str(counting_time/60000).zfill(2)
        counting_seconds = str( (counting_time%60000)/1000 ).zfill(2)
        counting_millisecond = str(counting_time%1000).zfill(3)

        counting_string = "%s:%s:%s" % (counting_minutes, counting_seconds, counting_millisecond)

        counting_text = font.render(str(counting_string), 1, (255,255,255))
        counting_rect = counting_text.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center)

    screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
    screen.blit(counting_text, counting_rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(25)
```

Comment: It keeps rendering the new numbers on the old ones and it looks like a mess, how do fix that?

Comment: In example I clear screen ( `screen.fill( (0,0,0) )`) before I display new numbers.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to add that, but I have several other stuff rendered on the screen and when I fill the screen it goes blank, so how can I try to only fill the part where the clock is and not the whole screen?

Comment: Many programs/games render everything in every frame/loop.   
 
But you can:
__a)__ use `background=` in `render(text, antialias, color, background=None)` (see [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render))
__b)__ create small [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) and blit it before you blit text.
You can use `my_surface.fill()` to fill this surface with one color or [background_image.subsurface()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) to copy part of original background

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a built in method for this in pygame but here is how I would do it.

1. `import time`
2. Before you enter your game loop, store the time when you started running it with
   `startTime = time.time()` this will be considered your zero time.
3. Create a new label that draws `str(time.time() - startTime)` as its text every update. You subtract time.time() which is the current time, from the zero time to get the time elapsed since the loop started and there you have your timer.
4. If you want it rounded to seconds you need to make sure to truncate the time value to an int because otherwise it will be a decimal `str(int(time.time() - startTime))`

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: pygame has [pygame.time.get_ticks()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) so mostly you don't need `time` library.